# Unexpected htaccess behaviour (mod_rewrite and apache)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-routing, error-log

Yeah, mod_rewrite is driving me crazy.

Here is the problem:

my htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$    index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

when i try to access the page `advantix` (so address was `www.mywebsite.com/advantix`), i'm being redirected to `advantix/?url=advantix`

Looking at the access log, i have a suspicious 301 in the middle

```
"GET /advantix HTTP/1.1" 301 335 "-" "Mozilla/5.0"
"GET /advantix/?url=advantix HTTP/1.1" 200 186 "-" "Mozilla/5.0"
```

There is one important detail: **advantix is a directory**.

So, if i comment that rule, `advantix` goes to the folder and list the files.

Why it applies automatically the `/` if there's a folder matching?

**I don't want to reach the folder, i want to reach** `index.php?url=advantix` **with a call to** `advantix`.

I have the rewriteLogs too, but they didn't help more. My vhost conf has `Directory` tag  with `Options All`, if helps, i don't know much about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn off the [DirectorySlash](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash) Apache directive. This seems to be causing the 301 redirect.

```
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: no problem. although i was aware of this functionality but was not aware of the exact directive till now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this once:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$    index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: this obviously take me to the folder listing, and i don't want this.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. My solution is to stop rewriting URL on "bad" paths (directories without slash at the end):

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ $1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/*$ index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]
```